# complex combine sql

Tags: sql, database, hibernate

query 1 : this will count all the record with email 'emali@test.com'

```
select count(*) as total from userbase
join extrauserinfofromhrms on userbase.username = extrauserinfofromhrms.useremail
right join logevent on userbase.username = logevent.useremail
join eachworkflow on logevent.workflowid= eachworkflow.workflowid
where logevent.actionname ='complete'  and logevent.useremail like 'email@test.com'
```

query 2: list all user with emails..

```
select userbase.username from userbase
join extrauserinfofromhrms on userbase.username = extrauserinfofromhrms.useremail
```

how to use query2 to list all users with emailaddress and use each emailaddrses as parameter in query1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is a set-based language.  It works best when we stop thinking in a row-by-row fashion.  What you ought to be using is an aggregating query this:

```
select userbase.username  
      , count(*) as total 
from userbase 
    join extrauserinfofromhrms on userbase.username = extrauserinfofromhrms.useremail 
    right join logevent on userbase.username = logevent.useremail 
    join eachworkflow on logevent.workflowid= eachworkflow.workflowid 
where logevent.actionname ='complete'  
and logevent.useremail like 'email@test.com' 
group by userbase.username 
/
```